# iOS in App user assistance screens

Tags: ios

Our app involves the use of techniques that have not been used within the target profession before, and as a result, end users will have no comprehension of how to use it.  We will be doing webinars to help them get started with it; however, there is a concern that they may need some immediate assistance from the time they download it.

So, we're trying to figure out how best to present this information.  While the app itself is mostly self-explanatory, the underlying techniques on how it is to be used require some explanation.

I'm thinking of adding a "help button" on the nav bar at the top of screens where it will be relevant, which would then open a webview to load html containing the necessary help screens.

My questions are:

a) Would this generally be acceptable in terms of the UI?

b) Is there a better way than what I'm suggesting?

TIA

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about UX/UI (so it belongs to the UX/UI stack exchange site).

Answer (score 1):

A: No. I think a help button is the wrong way to go about it. 
B: Why not display a screen onto of the UI that gives info on how to use the app. This screen only shows the first time the user opens the app. Like a short tutorial?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.  The help files aren't really about using the app as much as they are about using the techniques that underly the app.   Kind of hard to explain.  So, it is possible users would have to refer back to them with some frequency even after an extended period of use.  

Would you still suggest a more context-sensitive form of help?  Thanks.